# Active Directory using old logon script

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

I applied a logon script to a specific user within AD User management. Removing the script or even the file continues to run that logon script. How can I remove this?

I have run gpupdate /force on all 3 Domain Controllers but not luck. There are already existing logon scripts applied to the groups the user is a member of.

Comment: Try to set the logon script, but to blank.

Comment: @harrymc I have done this, as well as clicked apply but still uses the old logon script

Comment: @S_T Is the login script here still causing problems or did you figure it out?  I wasn't sure if you are referring to a logon script from a GPO or from the AD User account `Profile` tab and the `Logon script` specified there that is at `\\yourdomain.com\netlogon`. If you remove the script from netlogon, try running `repadmin /syncall /AdeP` from one of the DCs and it will force replication across. From the client machine run `gpupdate /force` and then reboot it. I will assume it was just a timing thing in this case and you have it handled, but figured I'd ask just in case.